# Facebook doesn't let share my website pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments, facebook-sharer

I want to use facebook share and like button from my website and especially facebook comments but facebook says that my website is characterized as UNSAFE and wouldn't let my users share the pages on FB.

Any help ?

The URL : http://www.songzong.net/songs/957/Baat-Bann-Gayi.html

Thanks

Comment: The URL is blocked - submit it to the debugger and click the "If you think you are seeing this by mistake, let us know" link - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.songzong.net%2Fsongs%2F957%2FBaat-Bann-Gayi.html

Comment: David, already done that dozens of times in last 6 month and yet no reply .

Comment: Maybe it is because your website plays music as soon as you visit the page?